# In python, how do I replace a column of misspelled names with the correct names from another dataframe along with the columns of data in the 2nd one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, data-cleaning, fuzzy-search

I have two dataframes. df1 has official, clean data on a few hundred people. Data like names, addresses, gender, race, etc. And df2 is simply a list of people who attend various clubs so their names are potentially entered multiple times for various clubs. df2 was also entered manually, so there are some misspellings and nicknames. Everyone in df2 should have one entry in df1 that represents them.
I need accurate statistics regarding the club members. Fuzzywuzzy is really cool for being able to find approximate matches quickly, but it’s almost certain to false positively and/or false negatively match a couple of people depending on the set cutoff point.
So, how do I replace the names in df2 with their closest match in df1 along with the columns of data in column 1 associated with them? Also, is there a simple, mathematical way I can find the right cutoff balance and how do I identify the most uncertain results after that?

My first strategy to solve this problem was to ask GPT-3.5 to do it for me (I know it's shameful, but I'm very much a coding novice. Also, GPT-4 rejects my credit card.). There were dozens of attempts made with differing results and minor adjustments made by myself. The code I'm getting usually works. But, since I'm no master coder, I'm just not confident about how to get the code to do exactly what I want. For example, it seems to be finding approximate matches, but not combining the dataframes how I want. Here's the code I used:

```
score_cutoff = 80

# Define a function to match rows based on similarity to all three columns
def match_rows(row, df):
    Name = row['Full Name']
    ID = row['ID Number']
    max_score = 0
    max_row = None
    for i, r in df.iterrows():
        score1 = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Name, r['Full Name'])
        score2 = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(ID, r['ID Number'])
        avg_score = (score1 + score2) / 2
        if avg_score > max_score:
            max_score = avg_score
            max_row = r
    if max_score >= score_cutoff:
        print("df2 Row:\n", row)
        print('\n')
        print("Skyward Match:\n", max_row)
        print("Score:", max_score)
        print('\n------------------------------------------------------------\n')
        return max_row
    else:
        return None

# apply the match_rows function to each row in the inaccurate dataframe
matches = df2.apply(match_rows, axis=1, args=(df1,))

# create a new column in df2 indicating whether or not a match was found and the entry got replaced

df2['Matched']=False
for i, r in matches.iteritems():
    if r is not None:
        df2.loc[i, ['Full Name', 'ID Number']] = r[['Full Name', 'ID Number']
        df2.loc[i, 'Matched'] = True

# print the final matched dataframe
print(df2)
```

The code below "create a new column in df2" was added when I asked for a column that shows whether the df2 row found a match in df1 to replace it (I wanted to make sure all df2 entries got replaced with a validated name) but I'm not sure if that's working either. Any advice would be greatly appreciated and examples of code would be doubly so!

Edit: Here's a sample of what the dataframes look like per request.
[image: This is df1 with their validated names and data]

[image: And this is df2. It's essentially just a lot of various attendance sheets that I stacked so there are a lot of repeats.]

Comment: Could you share how your df1 and df2 look like? No need for the full data, just a couple of rows with fake data to show the columns.

Comment: I've added the data frame examples as requested.

Comment: Does df2 contain just the name or both name and ID number?

Comment: It has both, so most people would probably say I could just look for exact matches among the IDs. But they are manually entered and I've noticed there are at least a few invalid entries that need to be corrected. Hence I'm trying to match by average similarity in both columns.

Answer (score 0):

From my research, the best package to use for fuzzy matching at the moment seems to be [rapidfuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz). It is actively maintained and has a complete [documentation](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/index.html).

### Code Snippet

The following is one approach to perform fuzzy match of each row in df2 to the population of df1.

```py
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz
import pandas as pd
from typing import Callable

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'Full Name': ['Patrickson, Jessica Gloria', 'Bennett, Franklin Scotty', 'Aguirre Rodriguez, Diego Andre'],
        'ID Number': ['7561863', '4863187', '6453152'],
        'Gender': ['F', 'M', 'M'],
        'Race': ['Caucasian', 'Caicasian', 'Caucasian'],
        'Hispanic': ['N', 'N', 'Y'],
        'Age': [23, 19, 29],
        'State': ['NY', 'UT', 'TX'],
        'City': ['New York City', 'Salt Lake City', 'Austin'],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'Full Name': ['Jessica Smith', 'Frank Bennett', 'Diego Rodriguez', 'Frank Bennet'],
        'ID Number': ['7561863', '4863187', '6453152', '4863187'],
    }
)

def custom_scorer(w_name: float, w_id: float, sep: str = '#') -> Callable:
    """Custom scorer for process.extractOne.

    The scoring depends on two scores: similarity for name and similarity of ID
    However, we can impart different weight on each score. For example, if we
    have more confidence on the accuracy of ID than name, we can give higher
    weight to the similarity of ID than name. In real practice, w_name and
    w_id shall be tweaked based on the data, but the two weights should sum up
    to 1.

    :param w_name: weight for name similarity
    :type w_name: float
    :param w_id: weight for ID similarity
    :type w_id: float
    :param sep: separator between name and ID in the query and choice strings,
        defaults to '#'
    :type sep: str, optional
    :return: a helper function that is passed to process.extractOne
    :rtype: Callable
    """
    
    def helper(query: str, choice: str, **args) -> fuzz.WRatio:
        """This helper function is the one returned by custom_scorer.

        It is also what is actually supplied to process.extractOne.

        :param query: query string, must be in the form of name + {sep} + ID,
            where the separator is supplied by custom_scorer
        :type query: str
        :param choice: choice string, must be in the same format as query
        :type choice: str
        :return: custom computed similarity score between query and choice
        :rtype: fuzz.WRatio
        """
        q1, q2 = query.split(sep)
        c1, c2 = choice.split(sep)
        r1 = fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio(q1, c1)
        r2 = fuzz.ratio(q2, c2)
        return w_name * r1 + w_id * r2 

    return helper

def match(
    row: pd.Series,
    population: pd.Series,
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    score_cutoff: int,
    w_name: float,
    w_id: float,
    sep: str,
) -> pd.Series:
    """Match the best row in population for the given row.

    :param row: a row in the dataframe to match
    :type row: pandas.Series
    :param population: population from df1 as a list of strings. Each person
        is represented by their full name and ID number concatenated together
    :type population: pandas.Series
    :param df: dataframe where the population is acquired from.
    :type df: pandas.DataFrame
    :param score_cutoff: the minimum score to consider a match
    :type score_cutoff: int
    :param w_name: weight for name similarity
    :type w_name: float
    :param w_id: weight for ID similarity
    :type w_id: float
    :param sep: separator between name and ID in the query and choice strings,
    :type sep: str
    :return: the best match row from df for the current row. If a match is not
        possible, return the current row.
    :rtype: pandas.Series
    """
    m = process.extractOne(
        row['Full Name'] + sep + row['ID Number'],
        population,
        scorer=custom_scorer(w_name, w_id, sep=sep),
        score_cutoff=score_cutoff,
    )
    if m is not None:
        return df.iloc[m[2]]  # matched row index in population
    return row  # match failed


# These are the params to tune
score_cutoff = 80
w_name = 0.4
w_id = 0.6
sep = '#'

# info of all the people to match, obtained from df1 and converted into a
# list of strings
population = df1[['Full Name', 'ID Number']].apply(
    lambda row: row['Full Name'] + sep + row['ID Number'], axis=1,
)

# Find the matching row in df1 for each row in df2, stored in df3
df3 = df2.apply(
    match, axis=1, args=(population, df1, score_cutoff, w_name, w_id, sep),
)
df3 = df3[df1.columns]  # reorder columns to match df1

print(df3)
```

The resulting `df3` is:

```
                        Full Name ID Number Gender       Race Hispanic  Age  \
0      Patrickson, Jessica Gloria   7561863      F  Caucasian        N   23   
1        Bennett, Franklin Scotty   4863187      M  Caicasian        N   19   
2  Aguirre Rodriguez, Diego Andre   6453152      M  Caucasian        Y   29   
3        Bennett, Franklin Scotty   4863187      M  Caicasian        N   19   

  State            City  
0    NY   New York City  
1    UT  Salt Lake City  
2    TX          Austin  
3    UT  Salt Lake City
```

### Explanation

- The basic tool used is `process.extractOne`, which does all the heavy lifting of finding the best match row in `df1` for the current row in `df2`. The majority of the code given by ChatGPT in the OP is doing `process.extractOne` manually, with much worse performance of course.
- The logic of matching is customized (see `custom_scorer`). Since we have two columns to match, yet `rapidfuzz` only allows for direct string to string match, we first concatenate the two strings together (see the creation of `population`), with a separator between name and ID. And then split them up during the actual scoring process (see the `helper` function inside `custom_scorer`).
- We can obtain two similarity scores, one for name and the other for ID. We can take average of them, which essentially is imparting the same weight on these scores. However, empirically, the likelihood of making mistakes in recording name and ID are different. Thus, their weights shall be different as well. Exactly what weight should be given to name similarity and ID similarity is open for discussion. Mostly, this is data-dependent. In other words, one has to use cross validation to find the best weight designation. In the example above, the weight of name similarity (`w_name`) is set to 0.4 and the weight of ID similarity (`w_id`) is set to 0.6 (i.e., we believe a match in ID can outweigh a mismatch in name).
- The similarity scoring methods for name and ID are different. For name, `fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio` is used, because name contains multiple tokens with possibly different ordering (as exemplified in the distinct ways first and last name are treated in df1 and df2). It makes sense to compare only the sorted unique tokens of names. For ID, `fuzz.ratio` is used, because ID shall contain only one token. So a direct `fuzz.ratio` suffices.

### What's Next?

1. In the example above, there are three parameters that need tuning: `score_cutoff`, `w_name`, and `w_id`. One should perform cross validation to tune these parameters, and choose a set that fits the data the best.
2. If `df1` or `df2` is extremely large, one might want to investigate performance improvement. But most of the time, it should NOT be an issue if the population does not go into hundreds of thousands. Always keep in mind that "premature optimization is the root of all evil -- Donald Knuth".